# AnimatedBuilder in flutter

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-animation

I have an animation and can't understand one thing in this code

```
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController _controller = AnimationController(
    duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
    vsync: this,
  )..forward();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Material(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
      AnimatedBuilder(
                animation: _controller,
                builder: (context, child) {
                  return AnimatedPositioned(
                    top: ((size.height) * _controller.value) + 100,
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                    curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                    left: 0,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 250,
                      width: size.width * 0.6,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
          ]
        )
      );
  }
}
```

This code creates a container and animates its position.
The thing I am unable to understand is I have specified a duration (500 milliseconds) in `AnimatedPositioned` and have specified 3 seconds as duration for `_controller`

1. Why the box animates in 3 sec and not in 500 milliseconds
2. The animation does not follow the curve initially (i.e it moves linearly and then after some time it decides to follow the curve)

I am still learning animations so it can be a silly doubt but I really can't understand it.
If someone can explain whats going on with relevant code examples it would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your code you have specified duration to AnimatedPositioned widget.basically AnimationController interpolates from 0-1 in the duration specified  which is 3 secs in your example.With each smallest change in value of animationController the animatedBuilder is getting rebuilt and simulatenously we also see there is change in the value of top of `AnimatedPositioned` widget but by the time it starts animating animatedBuilder is getting rebuilt again.This scenario continues until AnimationController completes its animation(i.e interpolation from 0-1 for 3 secs).
Post the animationController completes `AnimatedPositioned` widget starts animating its top value based on the lastValue(at the end of 3 secs) to currentValue It animates using the duration and curve specified to it.

To summarize you will see two animations happening first one(one with AnimationController) takes 3 secs and the second animation(using AnimatedPositioned) takes 500 milliseconds. The second animation always tries to complete its animation but since its wrapped in AnimatedBuilder it ends up finishing its animation at the end of 3 secs.

The way AnimatedPositioned works is for each change in Property of this widget on rebuilding widgets (e.g by setState) you see the widget animating from its oldValue to new Value within the duration specified.

e.g you have specified
`top: ((size.height) * _controller.value) + 100,`
when the value of top is changed e.g you assign it to lets say 100 by doing setState then you will see the curves and duration taking effect and the widget animating  vertically from the original value to 100.

AnimatedContainer(),AnimatedPositioned() etc this type of widgets work without the AnimationController and in that case you would need to provide duration to these widgets.

I would recommend taking a look at [The AnimatedPositioned Widget's example here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedPositioned-class.html), which basically explains the example that I gave above

Comment: But if I remove `AnimatedPositioned` and instead wrap it with a standard `Positioned` widget I don't exactly get the same animation effect. So, I guess it is not just lying around. Also if I decrease the duration of `AnimatedPosition` then the animation becomes faster. Same is with the curve passed in it, in short they surely take effect

Comment: sorry I shouldn't have mentioned that its not taking effect, I ran your code so I understand now whats happening let me update the answer with more details,

Comment: I have updated the answer, Also may I know what are you trying to achieve maybe I can help.

Comment: Thanks you for a detailed explanation.
Also, you are saying that when the controller value is changed `AnimatedPositioned` widget starts the animation but since the controllers value updates before the animation is finished it starts over again and by the end of 3 secs the position animation is actually performed and completed right ?

Comment: yes the positioned animation starts and completes after the animationController finishes the animation (in this example).